# Customize UILabel's Behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am new to iphone.i found `UILabel` instance  methodes very hard for me to implement.how can i use it.how can i customize the appearance of your text of a `UIlabel` further by subclassing  `UILabel`.Plz i need little help to initiate.Foe example i have a label in my `viewController` how can i custmize it's text and hoe to subclass
.thanks in advance.

Comment: in xcode, when you created an object, say UILabel *label; try typing the "label" then space press esc  , xcode will present the methods your object owns, "label" then . (dot) xcode will present the properties your object owns. that can guide you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use so many properties of a `UILabel` like:

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 40)];
lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];    // For setting font style with size
lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];        //For setting text color
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  // For setting background color
lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;   // For setting the horizontal text alignment
lbl.numberOfLines = 2;                       // For setting allowed number of lines in a label
lbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; // For setting line break mode
lbl.text = @"TitleText";                            // For setting the text inside the label
```

Let me know if any thing other than this you want to know!!

The two methods

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines
{
    return CGRectInset(bounds, MARGIN, MARGIN);
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawTextInRect: CGRectInset(self.bounds, MARGIN, MARGIN)];
}
```

We are using CGRectInset to create a rectangle that is either larger or smaller than an existing rectangle (`bounds`).

For Smaller rectangle, use positive values as `MARGIN`
For Larger rectangle, use positive values as `MARGIN`

All the best!!!

Comment: tell me how to implement these two methodes.
    
    
    – textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:
    – drawTextInRect:

Comment: Got the idea about the two methods?